# Is there a free Aussie TV guide for the mac similar to FreeEPG

Tags: mac, media-center

I am thinking to use EyeTV on my mac instead of vista for recording TV. On Windows you can use [FreeEPG](http://epgstream.net/) instead of the paid [IceTV](http://www.icetv.com.au/) guide service.

Is there equivalent software on the mac that gets the oztivo feeds and makes them available for IceTV or other recording software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shepherd](http://svn.whuffy.com/) pulls in its EPG data from multiple sources, including oztivo.  Instructions for integrating with EyeTV are [here](http://svn.whuffy.com/index.cgi/wiki/Installation#IntegrationwithEyeTV).

<sub>Not an EyeTV user.</sub>

Comment: Can't get Shepard to install. cpan blows up trying to install one of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/610478.html) on Whirlpool seems to indicate the latest version has an EPG for Australia. I have not used EyeTV before so I cannot personally vouch for it

Comment: That post refers to IceTV, which I mentioned in the question I DON'T want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If your tuner card is a DVB-T card, then you can also use the EPG information off the DVB-T streams. Most Australian networks now provide more than a week's worth of program data and have done for close to two years. The only wrinkle is that the EPG data doesn't take into account overruns, which Seven and Nine are horribly prone to.

Comment: Oh hell yeah they are, I don't think they EVER stop on schedule.

Comment: ABC and SBS are pretty good at running to time, actually, and Ten normally only slips badly with live shows.